# Reusing stream when calculating MD5 and SHA256 of Azure Blob

Tags: c#, .net, hash, stream, azure-blob-storage

I have to calculate MD5 and SHA256 of a file stored in Azure Blob Storage Account using Azure Function. I've tried to download file to a memory using [DownloadContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blobbaseclient.downloadcontent?view=azure-dotnet) method, but with large files (more than 4GB) I'm running out of memory (I'd have to scale up which is expensive). I found another method [DownloadStreaming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blobbaseclient.downloadstreaming?view=azure-dotnet) which works fine for first calculation (almost no additional memory usage), but before calculating 2nd hash I have to download the file again, because the stream is kind of empty. I've tried to call `Position = 0` on that stream, but I was getting not supported type of exception. Is there any way to use [DownloadStreaming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blobbaseclient.downloadstreaming?view=azure-dotnet) without re-downloading the file?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
var sourceFile = await blobClient.DownloadStreamingAsync();
byte[] md5Result;
byte[] sha256Result;

using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
{
   md5Result = md5.ComputeHash(sourceFile.Value.Content);
}

sourceFile = await blobClient.DownloadStreamingAsync();
using (var sha256 = SHA256.Create())
{
   sha256Result = sha256.ComputeHash(sourceFile.Value.Content);
}
```

Comment: You'll want to stream the content somewhere for keeping, in your case you'll probably want to stream it to the disk, and then open a [`FileStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=net-7.0) which supports seeking and then calculate the hash sums from there. But, YSK, that Azure Blob Storage supports storing the MD5 hash alongside the file itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the stream in a loop, and use `md5.TransformBlock` and `sha256.TransformBlock` manually to compute the hashes bit by bit.

- You don't need to pass an `outputBuffer` to that function, you can pass `null`.
- You need to call `TransformFinalBlock` before retrieving the hash.
- Consider using `CancellationToken` on async functions.

```cs
var inputBuffer = new byte[4000];
using var sourceFile = await blobClient.DownloadStreamingAsync();
using var md5 = MD5.Create();
using var sha256 = SHA256.Create();

int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = await sourceFile.ReadAsync(inputBuffer.AsMemory())) > 0)
{
    md5.TransformBlock(inputBuffer, 0, bytesRead, null, 0);
    sha256.TransformBlock(inputBuffer, 0, bytesRead, null, 0);
}
md5.TransformFinalBlock(inputBuffer, 0, 0);  // finish hash calculation
var md5Result = md5.Hash;

sha256.TransformFinalBlock(inputBuffer, 0, 0);  // finish hash calculation
var sha256Result = sha256.Hash;
```